# Efficient caching of ints with double key

Tags: c++, optimization

My code gets measurements from a device that has differing precision between different ranges. The measurement is received as a `double` and I want to transform it into an `int`, which is the index of my internal array that stores all possible values without gaps between them.

The code is currently:

```
struct Range
{
    double  FirstVal;
    double  Precision;
}

class Measure
{
    std::vector<Range> mRangeList;   // Gets filled with ascending ranges
    int* mStartIdxAtRange = nullptr; // Gets filled with starting incides for each range

    int ValToIdx(double val) const
    {
        // Find the precision for the current range
        int rangeAffinity = static_cast<int>(mRangeList.size()) - 1;
        for (int i = rangeAffinity - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (val< mRangeList[i+ 1].FirstVal)
            {
                rangeAffinity = i;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        double howMuchBigger = val- mRangeList[rangeAffinity].FirstVal;
        int retIdx = mStartIdxAtRange[rangeAffinity] + howMuchBigger / mRangeList[rangeAffinity].Precision + 0.5;
        return retIdx;
    }
}
```

The problem is that ValToIdx gets called a lot, and is the most expensive function after profiling. I wanted to cache the values so I tried this:

```
mutable std::unordered_map<double, int> Measure::mValToIdxCache;

int Measure::ValToIdx(double val) const
{
    auto it = mValToIdxCache.find(val);
    if (it != mValToIdxCache.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }

    // Find the precision for the current range
    int rangeAffinity = static_cast<int>(mRangeList.size()) - 1;
    for (int i = rangeAffinity - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (val< mRangeList[i+ 1].FirstVal)
        {
            rangeAffinity = i;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    double howMuchBigger = val- mRangeList[rangeAffinity].FirstVal;
    int retIdx = mStartIdxAtRange[rangeAffinity] + howMuchBigger / mRangeList[rangeAffinity].Precision + 0.5;
    mValToIdxCache[val] = retIdx;
    return retIdx;
}
```

However, this makes the function 3 times slower. How can I cache the indices for each value, so that the cache is faster to access than just computing it from scratch?
For any given run of the software, it can be assumed that measurement values will be in 1 to 3 ranges out of ~10 available ranges in the `vector`.

Comment: memoization on double wont work, because under the hood you are comparing for equality. Cant you do some kind of quantization before you do the actual transform? E.g. `int valx = val / some_value;` and then use that value for memoization

Comment: You can iterate through quite a few elements in a vector faster than looking up a value in an unordered_map.  The STL data structures have behavior requirements on them which force them to be slow in many common cases.

Comment: Have you considered a dichotomic search ?

Comment: Can you provide more details about that transformation from a double to an int ?

Comment: You probably need to optimize for cache hits, which requires more information. How many Measures are there? What operations happen between calls of ValToIdx() that could cause the Measures to be flushed out of cache? How long does a single call to ValToIdx() typically take at the moment?

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge There are 2-5 Measures in a run, these would not get flushed out until the end of the run. ValToIdx() is ~4% of program run time (without caching), and ~13% with unordered_map caching

Comment: @YvesDaoust I find the range that the value is in. I then see how much the value differs from the first value in a range. I then divide that by the precision, which is the difference between adjacent possible values within that range. I add this to the pre-calculated index of that first value in the range, and add 0.5 in order to round the number to the nearest int, in case of double precision errors.

Comment: @EyalK It would be useful to know the absolute time taken for ValToIdx() instead of percentages. In other words, I want an answer in nanoseconds. We can use that info to estimate how many cache misses are happening.

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge The line I got from instrumentation is:
Number of Calls =100,148,497
Elapsed Inclusive Time % = 8.90
Elapsed Exclusive Time % = 8.90
Avg Elapsed Inclusive Time = 0.00
Avg Elapsed Exclusive Time = 0.00

Comment: what range is `mRangeList.size()`?

Comment: @stefan it's in the last line of my question

Comment: @EyalK - Hmmm, the 0.00 isn't very useful :-) What's the total time taken for the program to run?

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge The program constantly takes measurements while it is running, so it stops only when closed manually

Comment: Am I right to think that you are rounding the value to an integer, with a granularity which differs in different ranges ? So this would be a piecewise linear function.

Comment: What are the values of the range bounds ?

Comment: @EyalK - Right, but for the run you gave the profile info for, if we knew the total run time, we could do this: time_per_call = (total_run_time * 0.089) / 100148497. As a rough guess, the function looks like it should take <20ns. If it is taking much longer than that, then there's probably something going wrong. When I say 20ns, I assume you're running on a modern-ish PC with an Intel i3 or better.

Comment: "measurement values will be in 1 to 3 ranges ": is that guaranteed ? And are the successive values correlated ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The range is not guaranteed, but empirically it doesn't go more than that. Successive ranges are not always correlated, but it is guaranteed that they are increasing in `FirstVal` and becoming less precise (`Precision` will also become larger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you add "int startIdx;" to the Range struct and remove mStartIndexAtRange from Measure? I suspect that would improve cache performance.

Also, can you store 1.0/Precision in Range instead of Precision. That way you could use a multiply instead of a divide eg:

```
int retIdx = mStartIdxAtRange[rangeAffinity] + howMuchBigger *
                mRangeList[rangeAffinity].ReciprocalPrecision + 0.5;
```

Comment: Will try and report back

Comment: Doing this gave me a little speed boost. Using a reference for mRangeList[rangeAffinity] also helped a bit. Funnily enough, precalculating `static_cast<int>(mRangeList.size()) - 1` helped the most

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of the question, I would solve it this way:

1) Assuming that the values are changing smoothly, the boundaries of the ranges will change by one index at a time and I would use a left or right sequential search, starting from the current range

```
if V < R[i]:
    i-= 1
    while V < R[i]:
        i-= 1
else
    while V >= R[i+1]:
        i+= 1
```

From one value `V` to the next, keep the index `i`. It can be initialized for instance with the middle index.

When you stay in the same range, this takes 2 comparisons. If you get to the next lower range, 2 comparisons, and to the next higher range, 3 comparisons.

2) in principle you need to check that the index `i` remains in the allowed range (`0` to `rangeAffinity` excluded).

This can be avoided by having sentinel values: if necessary, extend the bounds array with very small and very large values, such that `V` is guaranteed to be in one of the intervals, and the range search snippet above will remain safe.

3) precompute two coefficients per interval, such that the whole conversion is made with

```
int(Ai + Bi * V)
```

Notice that, contrary to your `mStartIdxAtRange`, the coefficient `Ai` is double precision and already incorporates the 0.5 rounding term.

---

We don't know enough about the variations of `V`. But if it turns out that the rounded value frequently remains constant for a while, it might be beneficial to compute the range corresponding to that same rounded value and detect excursions from that range before anything else. In that case, there is no need to recompute the rounded expression.